# Where can I find a list of changes to Terminal.app in Lion?

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm thinking of upgrading to Lion after hearing that they've upgraded Terminal.app somewhat. The main thing I've heard is that Terminal.app now supports 256 colors, but I don't care about colors. I want mouse events in screen without using [MouseTerm](https://bitheap.org/mouseterm/).

Where can I find all the changes to Terminal.app provided by Lion? Are mouse events included in this update?

Comment: I'm also curious. All I can find from Apple is [this](http://www.apple.com/macosx/whats-new/features.html#unix). Maybe that's it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Terminal changes in Lion aren't very major, from what I've seen, but they're listed [here](http://www.apple.com/macosx/whats-new/features.html#unix). Still no mouse events, unfortunately. If you have access, I suggest [filing a feature request](http://bugreport.apple.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I don't use mouse events, but they appear to at least partially work in [iTerm 2](http://www.iterm2.com), which does not require Lion or MouseTerm.  I tested with "set mouse=a" in vim and was able to select using the mouse, etc.